# What's a drum cabinet?

Tags: single-word-requests

I stumbled upon this word "drum cabinet" and although I guess what it means I'm not 100% sure. There is a guy who is a background singer and he says he was placed behind the main singer and in front of the "drum cabinet". Does it simply mean that he was in front of the drums? Just curious, because I don't find a translation in none of the dictionaries.

Comment: It either (literally) means the cabinet where drums are stored or (figuratively) the dais on which a drum kit is often placed on a stage. More context is required to determine which it is.

Comment: It might refer to a [drum booth](https://www.acoustic-consultants.co.uk/drum-booths), which is a small room or cubicle in a recording studio used to record drums; because drums are much louder than other instruments, they can't just be played next to other instruments, and even if you're recording instruments as live you'll need something to absorb the drum noise to stop other mics picking it up. Acoustic screens are also used for a similar purpose. (In contrast, a drum or bass cabinet is an amplifier.)

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/ may be more use, as this seems to be musical terminology, so you want to ask musicians not grammarians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "drum cabinet" is not in dictionaries, then perhaps you should guess that it means "a cabinet for drums".  Those words are all in the dictionary.  The sentence you quoted tells you nothing more than that.

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked more than two years ago and GEdgar's answer accepted. But just for the record...

The box housing a *guitar*'s speaker is called its **cabinet**. It may also contains the amplifier. Whatever it contains, the box AND its contents are generally referred to as a cabinet or 'cab'. In a small venue it might be the guitar's only speaker: in a large one, where more speakers are required, the cab may only be needed by the guitarist him/herself. As a monitor.

With 'traditional' drums, a cabinet can't be used: the sounds need to be picked up by microphones and mixed. **But** if it's an **electronic** drum kit, an amp and a speaker (combined in a cabinet, for example) are *essential* as the drums don't make any noise without: only a bit of clicking.

So yes, the O.P. was right: the singer has been made to stand in front of the electronic drums speaker. *An unenviable position*! It will be hard for him to hear anything *but* the drums.

(Here's one: [The Roland PM-100 Personal Drum Monitor Amplifier](https://www.gear4music.com/Drums-and-Percussion/Roland-PM-100-Personal-Drum-Monitor-Amplifier/2A1T). "Featuring a rugged **cabinet** and a custom full-range speaker system - made up of a 10'' speaker and a powerful 80W amplifier.")

By the way, I think the singer would rather be called a *backing* singer than a *background* one!